# How do I reduce "Noise" within a model in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, noise-reduction

I am looking to reduce the volatility of a stock prediction model's plot. The idea is to be able to focus on a trend more than an exact guess.

[Example Output Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTNhf.png)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.plot(y_pred_org)     # real price over time
plt.plot(y_test_t_org)   # predicted price over time
plt.title('Prediction vs Real Stock Price')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.xlabel('Days')
plt.legend(['Prediction', 'Real'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You can calculate the moving average to get a smoother curve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options:

- As @Juan C stated, you can calculate a moving average.
- Or you could select fewer samples and then use spline interpolation to smooth the curve
  as explained here:
  https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-plot-a-smooth-line-with-matplotlib-in-python

Answer (score 0):

use standardscaler or minmaxscaler to normalize your data.   Also, if you have nan values use interpolation to smooth out the data.  Study preprocessing your data.  Let me know if you need help

see (https://github.com/dnishimoto/python-deep-learning/blob/master/College%20Graduate%20Admission%20SVC.ipynb)  I use scaler to normalize the data in the pipeline